# TTF character to vector

Tags: vector, pdf, svg, font-manipulation

I'm trying to use a single character from the font [Killigrew](http://www.urbanfonts.com/fonts/Killigrew.htm) as a symbol in `.svg` or `.jpg` format on my website.

However, the `.ttf` file is formatted incorrectly, so any image program I try to insert into as text the character is incorrectly cropped.

Is there a way for me to either fix the whole Killigrew `.ttf` or open it and convert the character I need directly into `.svg`, `.pdf`, or other vector format?

Comment: Soooo ... why don't you just draw it yourself?!

Comment: Not sure if I get it; but you could _create outlines_ in Illustrator/inkscape, and then you would have it as an image. Another - more convoluted option - is to create outlines, save as svg, upload to icomoon, and download as a font. But that might be rather stinky as to workflow and copyrights...

Answer (score 1):

as Random O'Reilly said. In addition, you can open Glyphs table in Illustrator to find exactly necessary symbol and put it at your artboard. Then you can outline it to get a vector shape and use as you need. Don't thinkg about fixing of TTF font, it is not so pretty in all :)